# Adding tags to textwriter?

Tags: c#, xml, stream

How do I add an `<abc>` tag in a start and `</abc>` tag in end tag in textwriter?

Comment: 3 questions: Do you want to create an XML document? What code do you already have (could you post a sample)? What is the desired output (post a short XML sample document)?

Comment: `TextWriter` just writes text, not tags. What are you trying to accomplish, and why did you think that a `TextWriter` would do it?

Comment: I am getting stream or textwriter/xmlwriter output from xslt transform with root element missing.i want to make it as a xml document so i can do processing on the xml

Answer (score 1):

Use an `XmlWriter`. Write your starting root element. Then pass the `XmlWriter` to the XSL transform. It will continue writing. When that's done, write your end root element:

```
public static void WrapTransform(
    Stream outputStream, 
    string styleSheetUri, 
    string documentUri)
{
    var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using (var styleSheetReader = XmlReader.Create(styleSheetUri))
    {
        transform.Load(styleSheetReader);
    }

    using (var wrapper = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream))
    {
        wrapper.WriteStartElement("Root");
        transform.Transform(documentUri, wrapper);
        wrapper.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai John,thanks for your answer.
This is what i have now.So How to get a XmlDocument out of this xmlwriter? 

 XmlWriter xmlwriter=XmlWriter.Create(stream1);
                xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
                xslTrans.Transform(xPathDoc1, null, xmlwriter);
                xmlwriter.WriteEndElement();

Thanks

Comment: Hai i solved the problem.Thanks for the answer given by John Saunders

Comment: Hai John, i solved with ur answer..thts the 1 needed 4 me..thnx.